# How to know the current changeset id TFS Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have this workspace on this machine that is not updated for some days. I want to know the latest changeset Id that exists on this machine.

Let's say the latest changeset that is checked-in is 8400. I want to somehow find the current changeset id of the workspace on this machine, that might be say for example 8329.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the tf history command can achieve that.

For your convenience, you can simply copy below strings and save as a `cmd`/`bat` file, then run it directly to get the latest changeset ID under the specific directory **within the local workspace**. (*In your scenario you need to enter the root path of your workspace*)

```
ECHO OFF

SET "VSDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"  :: For VS 2017

:: For VS 2015: SET "VSDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"

CD %VSDir%

SET /p LocalPath=Enter LocalPath: 

ECHO.

tf history %LocalPath% /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W

ECHO.
PAUSE
```

[image]

Besides, you can also use the Version Control client API to achieve that. 
For more information please refer to: [How to determine the latest changeset in your workspace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2009/01/26/how-to-determine-the-latest-changeset-in-your-workspace/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [tf history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/history-command?view=vsts) command. Go to root workspace folder and:

```
tf history . /recursive /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W
```